# Why aren't Scala/Java Class parameters Serializable

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I observed this behaviour in Scala, but I am assuming it's the same case in Java.

Using Beam as an example.
If you have

```
SomeClass(p: Pipeline, stringP: String){ 
val foo: PCollection[String] = p.apply("TestSerialization", ParDo.of(new DummyTransform(stringP))
}
```

It would crash the pipeline with a `NonSerializableException` during runtime, but if you do

```
SomeClass(p: Pipeline, stringP: String){ 
val foo: PCollection[String] = { 
    val serializedStringP = stringP 
    p.apply("TestSerialization", ParDo.of(new DummyTransform(serializedStringP)) 
  }
}
```

it would succeed.
How come the original value of `stringP` is not serializable?

Comment: Is probably because the class itself is not Serializable. And to pass a parameter of the class, you have to pass the whole class.